# Add multiple fields to the same recordName row in CloudKit

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckquery, recordtype

I am trying to save multiple values to CloudKit (Name, Username, Points). However, when I save them, they save separately in 3 different rows, like so:

[image]

I want to combine the Name, Username, and Points fields into one row so I can load them together.

Here is my **saving code:**

```
func saveToCloud(){
    let newName = CKRecord(recordType: "LeaderboardInfo")
    newName.setValue(firstName, forKey: "Name")
        database.save(newName) { (record, error) in
        guard record != nil else { return }
        print("saved record")
    }
    let newUsername = CKRecord(recordType: "LeaderboardInfo")
    newUsername.setValue(username, forKey: "Username")

    database.save(newUsername) { (record, error) in
        guard record != nil else { return }
        print("saved record")
    }
    let pointsCount = CKRecord(recordType: "LeaderboardInfo")
    pointsEarned = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(50)))
    pointsCount.setValue(pointsEarned, forKey: "Points")

    database.save(pointsCount) { (record, error) in
        guard record != nil else { return }
        print("saved record")
    }
}
```

Can someone please demonstrate how to save these records together instead of separately?

Along with that, I currently load them separately when it should be together...**Loading code:**

```
 func queryDatabase() {
    // Name
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "LeaderboardInfo", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, _) in
        guard let records = records else { return }
        let sortedRecords = records.sorted(by: { $0.creationDate! > $1.creationDate! })
        self.names = sortedRecords
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //  self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
              self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    // Username
    let query2 = CKQuery(recordType: "LeaderboardInfo", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    database.perform(query2, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, _) in
        guard let records = records else { return }
        let sortedRecords = records.sorted(by: { $0.creationDate! > $1.creationDate! })
        self.usernames = sortedRecords
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //  self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
              self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    // Points
    let query3 = CKQuery(recordType: "LeaderboardInfo", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    database.perform(query3, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, _) in
        guard let records = records else { return }
        let sortedRecords = records.sorted(by: { $0.creationDate! > $1.creationDate! })
        self.points = sortedRecords
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //  self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
              self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

I am looking to group my data together in both the saving and loading process.

P.S. If it helps anyone understand better, I am trying to make a public leaderboard containing all the users' names or usernames, and their points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating 3 separate records and setting one field, a different field, on each one. Instead, just create 1 record and set all 3 fields on it. Try something like this (I'm not really up to speed on SWIFT, so you may have to play with the syntax a little)

```
func saveToCloud()
{
    let newRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "LeaderboardInfo")

    newRecord.setValue(firstName, forKey: "Name")
    newRecord.setValue(username, forKey: "Username")

    pointsEarned = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(50)))
    newRecord.setValue(pointsEarned, forKey: "Points")

    database.save(newRecord) { (record, error) in
        guard record != nil else { return }
        print("saved record")
    }
}
```